# Windows dual monitor sizing issue

Tags: windows, windows-8, multiple-monitors

I have a 3 display windows 8 system.  Two are 24" monitors and one is a 27" monitor.  The 27" monitor is in the middle and one of the 24" monitors is flipped portrait on the right.  When I go to the screen resolution dialog box in Windows the 24" monitor and the 27" monitor appear to be the same size.  This means that the edges of the window don't line up.  Similarly the 27" monitor and the portrait monitor don't line up in the sense that when the mouse goes from the top of the 27" monitor to the portrait monitor, the pointer jumps downward.  However if I go from the bottom of the 27" monitor to the portrait monitor the pointer lines up correctly and transitions smoothly.

[image]

The screen Resolution window correctly identifies my 27" monitor as a Dell S2740L and the driver is up to date.  Also if it is relevant, the 27" monitor is hooked up using HDMI, the left monitor is hooked up using DVI and the portrait monitor is hooked up with HDMI -> DisplayPort with an Active HDMI to DisplayPort adapter.

Comment: All monitors the same resolution?

Comment: All three monitors have the same resolution 1920 x 1080.

Comment: then it should be the same size I believe. Physical size of monitor would not effect the image size/resolution. What you see in the settings is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images of the monitors are relative to the pixel resolution.  This will be why they all appear the same size regardless or physical dimension of the monitor.

[Monitor Resolution](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/image-size-resolution.html#about_monitor_resolution)

Comment: This is confirmed, though I don't understand why that is the case.  The resolution is the number of pixels displayed.so if  larger monitor is displaying the same number of pixels each pixel is displayed slightly larger. Truthfully I don't understand resolution well enough.  Thanks.

Comment: Adobe has about as thorough of an explanation as I could find.  There is more information on this page but I linked straight to the portion on monitor resolution.  Hope this extra info helps.  The link has been added to my answer.